# ngModel with ngFor in multiLevel object

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to use `ngModel` in multi `ngFor` loop in multi level object?

```
<div no-padding *ngFor="let addon of item.addons_list; let mainIndex= index">
  <div *ngIf="addon.has_sub">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let sub of addon.sub_list ; let sub1 = index">
      <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
        <ion-select dir="rtl" placeholder="{{ sub.name }}" [(ngModel)]="add[mainIndex][sub1]">
          <ion-option value="{{ch.id}}" *ngFor='let ch of sub.items'> {{ch.name}} </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean about the multi-level object?

Comment: What's the issue you are getting?

Comment: It seems that [(ngModel)]="add[mainIndex][sub1]" should be replaced with [(ngModel)]="addon[mainIndex][sub1]". Please check